# How to add an Action with a DateTime parameter?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to add an Action to my `Invoices` controller which has a `DateTime` parameter:

Here is my Controller with my action:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class InvoicesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IInvoiceRepository _repository;
    private readonly ILogger<InvoicesController> _logger;
    public InvoicesController(IInvoiceRepository repository, ILogger<InvoicesController> logger)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult FilterBy(DateTime date)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(_repository.GetInvoicesByDate(date));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = "Failed to get invoices by date";
            _logger.LogError("{0} {1}", errorMessage, ex);
            return BadRequest(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

I had in the `startup.cs` file this line:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "getInvoicesByDate",
                template: "api/Invoices/{action}/{date:DateTime}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Invoices", action = "FilterBy" }));
    }
```

What's wrong in my code ? Thank you

**UPDATE**

I would like an URL this: format `http://domain/api/invoices/filterby/2017-01-01`

Answer (score 3):

hm..
I think it is not typical route and parameter with ASP.NET WebAPI, I am also not sure it's WebSite or WebAPI.

It works for me (url format like: domain/api/invoices/filterby/2017-01-01):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class InvoicesController : Controller
{
    
    [HttpGet("[action]/{date}")]
    public IActionResult FilterBy(DateTime date)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(date);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = "Failed to get invoices by date";
            return BadRequest(errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

--

In my opinion, I would like to make it simple: only use route attribute with WebAPI.

only use app.UseMvc(); in Startup.cs [image]

add route attribute in controller:
[image]

Finally, make sure your WebAPI url with parameter(HTTP GET)

> http://localhost:xxxx/api/Invoices/FilterBy?date=2017-01-01

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I forgot to mention I want a URL format like this:
http://domain/api/invoices/filterby/2017-01-01/